# Android layout with 2 evenly spaced Buttons

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this layout that works correctly, a relative layout with a text view and two buttons spaced evenly below it.

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/entrypopup"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:padding="5px"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ad"
    android:background="#80000000">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/title" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Entry Popup..."
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
    <TableLayout android:id="@+id/TableLayout01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/title">
        <TableRow android:layout_weight="1">
            <Button android:id="@+id/buttonVisit" android:text="View"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <Button android:id="@+id/buttonCancel" android:text="Cancel"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

But running layoutopt it says that "this TableRow layout or its TableLayout parent is possible useless".

Is there a way to do this layout then without the tables?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Dump the `TableLayout` and `TableRow`, and just use a horizontal `LinearLayout` in their place. The "magic" is in your `0dip` width and `1` weight, which you already have.

Comment: Your awesome ;) had button with text below and the text could vary in size so the layout didn't even out properly, the 0dip did the trick :)